# Webpack directives

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am building a typescript/javascript package that will contain several JSON files.  I do not want those JSON files included in the bundle that webpack outputs.  I do want those files included in the output folder of the bundled javascript (copied from the node_module directory).  This would be similar to including images.

I would like to create directives that explain to webpack what to do vs writing documentation in hopes that somebody reads it and does it correctly.

I know that `copy-webpack-plugin` will do what I need to do, but not sure how to set up this directive.
Is it even possible?

So

1. MyPackage has JSON files
2. Another developer uses my npm-package
3. Developer uses web pack in their project
4. Developers webpack bundles the javascript, excludes my JSON files from the bundle, but copies them to the output directory.

Comment: Is it an option to have your javascript expose the JSON values by providing an api method like `getPackageJSON()`?

Comment: Yes the JSON is translations for our website, but I have 67 languages to support, and 3 different JSON files for each language.  I do not want to merge into a webpack bundle 67 x 3 json files when only 1 language is used at a time.  So I want to dynamically load as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out within the package.json
Create a folder called bin (whatever) on the same level as src.
Copy the contents that need to be included in the package but not compiled or bundled into javascript, such as json files.

Update package.json add the following entry
"files": [
"bin"
],

Now when publishing, the npm package will contain the bin directory.  When building within your project using webpack it will recognize this and include those files in the webpack build and deploy as part of the deployment but not in the javascript bundle.

Then from there, your javascript should reference the files similar to reading a file whether it be on the server or client sie.